# How to put my error code in Intelij IDEA to be in inside its supposed line instead of the very bottom of the code

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How can I Display my error message like Picture 1 instead of Picture 2?

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just drag it over to the toolbar
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just drag the run tool window and drop it to the right side panel.